# How to select first rows by group with order by clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to select the top 3 most selled books by author ordered by the most selled. Technically, I would like to select the top 3 rows by every ordered group.

This is what i have for now:

```
    select 
        author_id
        ,book_id
        ,count(book_id) top
    from book_author
    group by author_id, book_id
    order by author_id, top
```

Is there any workaround? I have googled and found examples but none were using the `order by`.

I hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select author_id, book_id, cnt
from (select author_id, book_id, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by author_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from book_author ba
      group by author_id, book_id
     ) ba
where seqnum = 1
order by author_id, cnt desc;
```